# How can I fix my basketball valve that has fallen into the ball?

Tags: equipment, basketball, maintenance

I was attempting to pump my basketball with a pumping needle and a wrong sort of pump. Half way I noticed the valve went inwards. Trying to use the needle to pull it back, it fell into the ball. Is there a way I can fix this with a bunch of usual home tools?

Answer (score 2):

To get a valve out of a basketball, I used a long flexible grabber. You can get them at autopart stores. They have a plunger that opens the claw at the other end. Get one with a small enough diameter to fit through the hole in the ball. Then grab the valve and pull it out.